# Use a unique Google's PageSpeed API Key for analysing several pages on different web sites

Tags: php, google-app-engine, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Is it possible to use a unique PageSpeed API Key for analysing several pages on different web sites?
if not, is there any api that could do the same?

Comment: Please contact the vendor for you support options, this looks like a configuration issue/question you face, less a programming question.